# Is SilverLight 4 Limited to Only 2 concurrent PollingDuplex Service Connection

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, callback

I'm developping a SL 4.0 Application using multiple PollingDuplex Services.

I'm facing in a strange behavior : after 2 connexions on my Duplex Polling Service (on the same SL client), i got a ServerTooBusyException.

So, SL 4.0 is limited to only 2 concurrent pollingduplex service connection for the same client ?

Is there a workaround for that ?

My SL application require to subscribe more than 2 times to the polling duplex service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer because I haven't done any work with PollingDuplex services, but sounds to me like a browser issue. I think the browser only allows two simultaneous connections. Try using the ClientHttp stack.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295%28v=VS.95%29.aspx